# Docker Compose up command times out frequently

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker For Windows and have a set of images that **are already built** on my docker host. When I try to use the `docker-compose up -d` command to start my environment, I frequently face i/o timeout errors for different containers. Usually, retrying helps but I am trying to automate this and can't expect to re-run the whole pipeline.

**Versions**:

`Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

`docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306`

**Command line logs**:

```
C:\workspace\AK_DOCKER_RISK\docker-compose>docker-compose up -d
Creating risk-svc ... 
Creating risk-svc ... done
Creating risk-prc ... 
Creating risk-web ... 
Creating risk-web ... error
ERROR: for risk-web  b'i/o timeout'
Creating risk-prc ... done
ERROR: for web  b'i/o timeout'

Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The error is observed randomly, sometimes for svc, or web or prc.

Can someone please explain why this error is occurring and more importantly - how to solve this issue?

This is my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: iis-core-web:1910.252
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./web/Dockerfile
    container_name: risk-web
    ports:
      - "9111:8080"
    tty: true
    links:
      - svc
    volumes:
      - ../RiskLogs/web:c:/RiskLogs
  svc:
    image: iis-core-svc:1910.252
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./svc/Dockerfile
    container_name: risk-svc
    ports:
      - "9112:8080"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ../RiskLogs/svc:c:/RiskLogs
  prc:
    image: iis-core-prc:1910.252
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./prc/Dockerfile
    container_name: risk-prc
    tty: true
    links:
      - svc
    volumes:
      - ../RiskLogs/prc:c:/RiskLogs
  # prevent creation of new network and use existing nat
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Comment: you should define `image:` or `build:` not combine them, on production docker-compose it is better to use image:. I also think `links` is deprecated and should be replaced by `depends_on` What is your docker and docker-compose version?

Comment: @MazelTov, thanks for the advice to use `depends_on`. I'd like to keep both the image and build option for the flexibility to use the `-build` argument along with `docker-compose up`. My docker version is `18.09.0, build 4d60db4` and docker-compose version is `1.23.1, build b02f1306`. I also updated the details on the question.

Comment: This has something to do with network. We also have the very same problem and it occurs only for containers that are bound together with internal nat network. Sometimes even whole Windows Server goes down because of it and requires restart. Unfortunately I don't have solution for it now, just noting that your issue is probably same as mine and is network related. Right now I'm trying to set depends_on in such way, that each networked container is started in sequence, rather than in parallel. I had this observation that when they align that way it works then. But that is yet to be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links is a legacy feature. Try user defined networks instead as per docs:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Comment: Thanks for the advise. However, the timeouts still occur even after using depends_on instead of links.